# Excel vba project in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am now engaging in an excel vba project. It's a excel front interface for the workers in a site with an Access database in the company network. I dont like much the VBE in Excel 2007, so im wandering if I can do this with VB.NET, which seems to be a more adorable IDE. And where can I find some resources on this? Or recommanded books? Thanks!

Im using Excel 2007 et VB.NET 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try Excel-DNA (free). There are many other products out there too. You can make it work with VB.Net Express also, you just need to add a reference to your excel SDK. Also, Add-in Express looks pretty nice. I've never tried it though (costs money).

Comment: i dont know what exactly an add-in is. My project is like an VBA designed interface with buttons that manipulate data in excel workbook and in Access database. The users are workers so open the excel then hit the menus to load those add-ins seems not an easy task..

Comment: Your project is an Add-in. You've written in it VBA, but a tool like Add-in Express makes it easier to write more capable Add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Visual Studio Tools for Office: VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx).

This allows you to develop using VB.NET (or indeed C#) but with full access to the Office automation facilities.

Comment: I'm not sure about almost the same. The libraries are quite different. But if you are using to writing VBA, VB.NET will feel reasonably familiar. P.S. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: You'll have to buy a real version of Visual Studio. It will be cheaper in the long-run than plugging on with VBA.